# Forms in natural language

Tags: forms, design-patterns, natural-language, user-generated-content

I would like to know the best UX pattern for implementing such forms. This will be used to setup the discount of a particular hotel.

The existing swing UI is designed in narrative forms and I am required to implement this as the new web UI. I have checked the natural language form concept a little bit but it has its own pros and cons and few negative feedback as well.

What is the better approach over natural language form and traditional forms?

[image]

This is the approach I have taken so far (traditional forms)
[image]

Comment: Hi Nuwan,
what does your current draft look like? We will not do your work for you, so please show some effort.

Comment: hi @Nash I don't want to get work done from you. I am just asking the better approach for this. I have updated the current status and traditional form approach that I have taken so far.

Comment: Who is the user here? A hotel staff member will likely prefer a well layed out traditional form as that will be faster for them. Your labels and controls are very far apart, increases mistakes and slows down users.

Answer (score 3):

Natural language forms are much suited in short queries. Like i would like to book a ticket to "Choose Destination" on "Choose Date". These are much intuitive and direct. You can check out Luke's post on [mad-libs form](https://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1007) to learn more. But when it comes to long forms, it can increase the load on the user.

Standard forms are lot easier when it comes forms that has to be filled frequently. For an enterprise product like the one you are designing, label and form field will do more good than sentence with a form field. I would suggest you break the form into 3 simple steps with titles & progress tracker. Say for example : Adults, Children, Review. In each step you can have multiple fields based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Lakshmanan Palani

Answer (score 2):

Here is a previous post about it with some more points of consideration - [Is it a "Natural language" form a good practice?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/103965/is-it-a-natural-language-form-a-good-practice)

> Can be very hard to deal with the lot of culture and languages.
>
> Harder to design help and error message
>
> It's hard to represent optional inputs, because it leads to empty sentences
>
> Can be hard to parse fast by the user
>
> Not good when it is more than a few field
>
> Require to have fields a minimum related to be put in the same paragraph

Some research about it - https://www.jroehm.com/2014/01/26/ui-pattern-natural-language-form/

The consensus seems to be better conversion rates and appropriate for short queries as a fun and intuitive way to fill a form.

In experience, this makes sense since filling words in a long paragraph quickly becomes tedious and annoying (reminds me of some primary school low effort tests) vs filling a short sentence.

The cons start to add up when considering having to craft a paragraph to fit all the fields while giving the user a much longer task to complete a form (think about all the form best practices it breaks).

In your case, it seems you can use natural language forms for a quick initial trip query (there are many examples of this in the second link above) while pushing all other fields as filter options in the search results page.

There are 3 concepts working separately here (1) Initial Search (2) Advanced Search and (3) Filter and Sort. Natural language forms is helpful in (1), and becomes counter productive in (2) and (3). Keep these 3 concepts separate in the UI, as users are familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas Hung